# Instantiate service on startup in Angular2

Tags: angular

I hava a (singleton) service that contains some code in the constructor which should be run directly after startup. That menas an instance has to be created immidiately when the app is loaded.

One possibility to instanciate the service is to put it in the constructor of the app component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private mySercive: MyService
...
```

but since I never use myService in this component I will get a warning like `mySerive is not used` and someone else in my team might delete the service. Is there a way to instanciate the serivce inside the app module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can provide a dummy `APP_INITIALIZER` and pass it as `dependency` like

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useMulti: true, deps: [MyService], useFactory: (myService) => null}]
```

Comment: `useMulti` is no longer present in Angular 8: It has been renamed to simply `multi`. Also `useFactory` should declare a function that returns a function like so: `useFactory: (myService) => () => null`.

Comment: For those of you facing a `TypeError: this.appInits[i] is not a function`, @PaulSiersma's comment is the solution :)

Answer (score -2):

When you put service in **NgModule declarations** means you instantiating service from there itself...

When you use this syntax:

```
constructor(private mySercive: MyService
```

in typescript it just to tell compiler about **TYPECASTING** it does not do anything with service....

TO check does really its just typescript related stuff or not...
remove it from constructor and create on variable with same typecast...

like this

```
class ComponentClass {
    mySercive: MyService;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I just added a `console.log` in the constructor of the service which is printed only when I added the service in the constructor of the component.