# Angular 2 - can I create global service without injecting explicit

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a service,  which role is to observe a stream of actions and call some functions depending on them.
In constructor of service class I just subscribe to observable and no other methods ale called from outside service. It this way, its rather like Guard than service. 
I declared this service as injectable and injected to root component, and it works. Service gets created, subscribes to observable and does its works. But my root component call no method of service - does not use it at all. 
Is there a more elegant way to inject service globally, without declaring in component which is not logical place for it?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614894/instanciate-service-on-startup-in-angular2/41614974#41614974