# When does the constructor of an injected service in angular run?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

In Angular 7, if we have a service declared as @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}), when does it's constructor execute? Does it execute upon the construction of a component that uses it (as a dependency) or does it wait until a method in that service is first called?

Note:
Since the service is a singleton, I use the service's constructor to initialize some values. I could create a "Initialize()" method and call that in the component's constructor instead but I find this aproach a little messy.

Comment: At the latest when it is injected to a component, but maybe earlier (implementation detail).

Comment: Service instances are created when injected. If you don't inject them, they do nothing, and in your final build, they will be tree shaked.

Comment: Why don't you just test it?

Comment: I am but the behavior is not consistent for some reason. When the route is first loaded it doesn't fire the service's constructor but when I refresh the browser it does!

Comment: @sdagkas I also am experiencing this behaviour

Answer (score 7):

The constructor of a class decorated with the `Injectable` decorator is called upon initialization of that class/service by the injector of a certain scope. You can't have multiple instances of the same service inside one scope, unless you force it by providing the service it via `{ provide: MyService, useClass: MyService, multi: true }`.

The `provideIn` option defines the scope the service belongs to, therefore using `provideIn: 'root'` tells the DI to inject the service by using the RootInjector. And since a service won't get initialized multiple times in one scope, the constructor of that service is called only once, when the DI needs to inject that service into another component/service/module the first time.

Comment: I have a situation in which the component that injects the service is constructed normally but the service's constructor doesn't run. The service's methods run normally though, I can call them from within the component and they work as they should.

Comment: Instances of services are created at the point they are first needed. When a component (or another service) requires a service, angular scans the Dependency Injection tree, and looks for a definition (and an instance of a service). If no instance of the injected service is found, Angular creates an instance of the injected service, and only then the constructor of an injected service runs.

Answer (score 6):

Instances of injected services are created at the point a component that requires them is first created or when another service that requires them is first instantiated.

When a component (or another service) that requires a Service as a dependency is created (or instantiated), Angular scans the Dependency Injection tree, and looks for a definition (and an instance of the injected service). If no instance of the injected service is found, Angular creates an instance of the injected service, and only then does its constructor run.

Another way to instantiate a service before an object (or another service) that require it are created, is to add it as a dependency to the `APP_INITIALIZER` in the `deps` array, like this:

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: () => () => null, deps: [MyService], multi: true }
```

This will create an instance of `MyService` when the app is initialized regardless of when other components/services that require it are created.
More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41614894/3944673).